# Solve in integers: $(x + y + z + v)^2 - 29w = 2023, xy + yz + zv + vx - w^2 = 475$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

**Problem:** Solve in integers the system of equations:
\begin{align}
(x + y + z + v)^2 - 29w &= 2023, \\ % Equation 1
xy + yz + zv + vx - w^2 &= 475.      % Equation 2
\end{align}

This problem is from the algebra section of a local high school math competition.

**My Work**

Let's say $S = x + y + z + v$. We have:

$S^2 - 29w = 2023$

$xy + yz + zv + vx - w^2 = 475$

The second equation is messy, but I will try to rewrite it using $S$.

$2(xy + yz + zv + vx) = S^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2)$

Substitute this into the second equation:

$S^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2) - 2w^2 = 950$

So, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 + w^2 = S^2 - 950$

From here, I know that I can substitute $S^2$ back into the first equation, but I do not think that I will get anywhere with that. Could I please get some help with where to go from here or if I have completely taken the wrong path? Does the solution have to do with Diophantine Equations? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user376343 great point, I will fix that real quick.

Comment: $S^2$ also includes $2xz+2yv$, not present in the second equation.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein oops! I forgot about that. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Is this competition still ongoing?

Comment: @StinkingBishop he said that it was an in-person day-long competition that ended a few weeks ago

Comment: In integers or positive integers?

Comment: @RezaRajaei All Integers

Comment: Let $x+z=a$, $y+v=b$, then $(a+b)^2-29w=2023$ and $ab-w^2=475$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $x+z=a, y+v=b$. Now the system turns into:

$$(a+b)^2-29w=2023$$
$$ab-w^2=475$$

In other words, $2023+29w=(a+b)^2\ge 4ab=4(475+w^2)=4w^2+1900$ (using a well-known inequality $(a+b)^2\ge 4ab$).

So, we are getting $4w^2-29w-123\le 0$, which has solutions $w\in[-3, 10.25]$, so as $w$ is an integer, it is in the range $-3,\ldots, 10$.

Using the first equation, we can quickly sieve out some values of $w$, because $2023+29w=(a+b)^2$ must be a square number. Of course, if $-3\le w\le 10$, then $1936\le 2023+29w\le 2313$, and in this range the only square numbers are $44^2=1936, 45^2=2025, 46^2=2116, 47^2=2209, 48^2=2304$. Out of those, only $1936=2023-3\cdot 29$ gives an integer value $w=-3$ and this gives $a+b=\pm 44$.

Now, we can find $ab=475+w^2=484$ and then solve for $a, b$ using Vieta formulae i.e. solving the quadratic equation $X^2\mp 44X+484=0$. This gives $a=b=\pm 22$.

Finally, the solutions are as follows: $x, y$ can be arbitrary integers, $w=-3$; for the rest, either $z=22-x, v=22-y$ or $z=-22-x, v=-22-y$.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But is it possible to solve the systems ever further and find the values for each variable or is there an infinite amount of solutions for x, y, v, and z? Thank you again!

Comment: The. set of solutions is infinite. In particular, you can pick $x$ and $y$ freely, as I said above.

Answer (score -3):

In this task, we are given two equations and we need to solve for integers. The given equations are:

1. (x+y+z+v)^2 − 29w = 2023
2. xy+yz+zv+vx − w^2 = 475

To solve the given equations, we need to use algebraic manipulation and solve for each variable step by step. Let's begin with the first equation:

1. (x+y+z+v)^2 − 29w = 2023

Expanding the left side of the equation, we get:

(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 + 2xy + 2xz + 2xv + 2yz + 2yv + 2zv) − 29w = 2023

Now, we can simplify the equation by grouping the variables:

(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2) + 2(xy + xz + xv + yz + yv + zv) − 29w = 2023

Let's focus on the second term and factor it:

2(xy + xz + xv + yz + yv + zv) = 2[(x+y)(z+v) + xz + yv]

Now, we can substitute this back into the equation and simplify further:

(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2) + 2[(x+y)(z+v) + xz + yv] − 29w = 2023
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 + 2(x+y)(z+v) + 2xz + 2yv − 29w = 2023

At this point, we can see that we have four variables and only one equation. We need another equation to solve for these variables. Fortunately, we have another equation given to us. Let's use it:

2. xy+yz+zv+vx − w^2 = 475

We can rearrange this equation to get:

w^2 = xy+yz+zv+vx − 475

Now, we can substitute this back into the first equation:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 + 2(x+y)(z+v) + 2xz + 2yv − 29(xy+yz+zv+vx − 475) = 2023

Expanding and simplifying, we get:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 − 27xy − 27yz − 27zv − 27vx + 58xz + 58yv + 29w = 13848

Now, we can substitute the value of w^2 from the second equation:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 − 27xy − 27yz − 27zv − 27vx + 58xz + 58yv + 29(xy+yz+zv+vx − 475) = 13848

Simplifying further, we get:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 − 1555 = 27(xy + yz + zv + vx − 475)

We can simplify the right side of the equation further by using the value of w^2:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 − 1555 = 27(xy + yz + zv + vx) − 27w^2

Substituting the value of w^2, we get:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 − 1555 = 27(xy + yz + zv + vx) − 27(xy+yz+zv+vx − 475)

Simplifying, we get:

27w^2 = 13002

Now, we can solve for w:

w^2 = 482
w = ±22

Substituting w = 22 in the equation x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 − 1555 = 27(xy + yz + zv + vx) − 27w^2, we get:

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 = 809 + 27(xy + yz + zv + vx)

We can see that the left side of the equation is a sum of squares, which means that the right side must also be a sum of squares. Therefore, we need to find four integers whose sum of squares is equal to 809. By trial and error, we can find that:

x = −13

y = −2

z =

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please ... "$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + v^2 = 809 + 27(xy + yz + zv + vx)$ We can see that the left side of the equation is a sum of squares, which means that the right side must also be a sum of squares. Therefore, *we need to find four integers whose sum of squares is equal to $809$.*" Did you read back what you wrote? Or did something else write the above text? If yes, this would not be violating our policy (yet) but might be violating their policy. Cf. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35342/what-is-our-policy-on-ai-generated-content

Comment: Tommy, simply enclose each of your equations or formulas with dollars \$ ... \$